# VBA Button Copy Sheet to Word Document Issue

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

The code below copies a sheet from my workbook and pastes it into a new Word Document. The only issue I am having is the Word Document opens and copies the info, but its stays on the bottom taskbar and doesn't actually open the page on the screen (If that makes any sense). Could someone please tell me what I'm missing ? Anything helps, thanks.

```
Sub btnExport()
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Range("C2:D60").Copy
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application.14")
With objWord
    .Documents.Add
    .Visible = True
    .Selection.Paste
    .ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior 2 'wdAutoFitWindow
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before your `End Sub`, just do this:

```
objWord.Activate
```

The application starts up like that in the task bar, in order to bring it in focus for user, you need to activate it. Alternatively you can also use the `AppActivate` statement, but this requires knowing the *name* of the document that's just been added. To do that, I assign another variable `doc` to the return of `Documents.Add` method, and then we can do `AppActivate doc.Name`:

```
Sub btnExport()
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim doc as Word.Document
Range("C2:D60").Copy
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application.14")
With objWord
    Set doc = .Documents.Add
    .Visible = True
    .Selection.Paste
    .ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior 2 'wdAutoFitWindow
End With
AppActivate doc.Name
End Sub
```